# Invalid parameter size value -1

Tags: c#, linq

Hi everyone,  I am trying to connect to my database and insert a new patient info.  When I run my application I get "Invalid parameter size value -1. The value must be greater than or equal to 0.
Parameter name: value" Please help can't figure out where to set the parameter.  Thanks

```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Data.Linq;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   using iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere;

   namespace...     
   public class PatientService
       {
        private const string ConnectionString = "Dsn=SQL Anywhere
                                  10;uid=DBA;PWD=sql;databasefile='C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\SQL Anywhere 10\\Samples\\Training1.db';";

        public void CreatePatientInfo(Patient patient)
            {
             DataContext patientDataContext = new DataContext(Conn);

             Conn.Open();

             Table<Patient> patientsTableList = patientDataContext.GetTable<Patient>();

             patientsTableList.InsertOnSubmit(patient);


             patientDataContext.SubmitChanges();
             Conn.Close();
            }
       }
```

My Patient class with mapping attributes

```
    using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

    namespace ...
    {
     [Table(Name = "patient")]
     public class Patient
    {
    public Patient()
    {
    }

    public Patient(string patientId, string firstName, string lastName, string address, string city, string state,
        string zipcode, string phoneNumber, string notes, int classificationId)
    {
        PatientId = patientId;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Address = address;
        City = city;
        State = state;
        Zipcode = zipcode;
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        Notes = notes;
        ClassificationID = classificationId;
    }

    [Column(Name = "patient_id", DbType = "char(5) NOT NULL", CanBeNull = false,
        IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public string PatientId { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "first_name", DbType = "char(40)", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "lastname", DbType = "char(40)", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Column( Name = "address", DbType = "char(40)", CanBeNull = true)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Column( Name = "city", DbType = "char(40)", CanBeNull = true)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Column( Name = "state", DbType = "char(2)", CanBeNull = true)]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Column( Name = "zipcode", DbType = "char(9)", CanBeNull = true)]
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "phone", DbType = "char(10)", CanBeNull = true)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Column( Name = "notes", DbType = "varchar", CanBeNull = true)]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [Column( Name = "classification_id", DbType = "int", CanBeNull = true)]
    public int ClassificationID { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: i hope your connectionstring field is not declared like that...

Comment: Have you checked all the values in 'patient' object if they are valid?

Comment: Yes I matched the with the values in the database.

Comment: at which line the exception is thrown? it's important and helps others answer your question quicker and better. Your code is fairly long and scanning through all the lines to find which line possibly throws the exception is not easy.

Comment: The exception is thrown when patientDataContext.SubmitChanges(); is called

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
[Column( Name = "notes", DbType = "varchar", CanBeNull = true)]
```

should be

```
[Column( Name = "notes", DbType = "varchar(250)", CanBeNull = true)]
```

for some value (I used 250)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's still throwing the same exception